# Serializable schedules

Tags: database, serialization, rdbms

So there was this question in my DBMS exam:

Define serializable schedule.

My answer: If a schedule can be converted to some serial schedule by a series of non-conflicting swaps of actions, then it is a serializable schedule.

They've marked it wrong. I have been arguing with the professors for quite some time but they want the definition from the book.

Can someone please point out where am I wrong?Are there any such schedules that cannot be converted to a serial schedule but are nevertheless, serial?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to know where you are wrong you have to give your demonstration that your definition is equivalent to the textbook one. You should have such an argument in the first place or you shouldn't hold the opinion that your definition is correct.

Comment: Your if-then phrasing is a poor way to give a definition. A definition should be written as if & only if. As is, if we didn't know you were giving a definition then we would just see a statement that gives sufficient but maybe not necessary conditions for serializability.

Answer (score 1):

your answer is wrong because it defines "conflict serializability" not "serial schedule"

A schedule is called serializable whenever executing the transactions sequentially, in some order, could have left the database in the same state as the actual schedule. Serializability is the commonly accepted criterion for correctness.